# PostgreSQL SELECT only alpha characters on a row

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I need to `SELECT` *only* alpha characters `FROM` a row though I'm having trouble with the expression. I've tried:

```
SELECT id, regexp_replace(_column_name_, '0123456789', '') AS _column_alias_
FROM _table_name_;
```

I know the general gist would only replace numbers however the column only contains alphanumeric characters to begin with.

So if `_column_name_` contains a value `a1b2c3` how do I make PostgreSQL return the string `abc`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ***fastest*** expression to eliminate all digits from a string is with a plain [`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT translate(col,'0123456789','') AS col_without_digits
FROM   tbl;
```

Regular expressions are powerful and versatile but more expensive.

Your mistake was the missing "global" switch as 4th parameter, as [pointed out by @Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159267/939860). While using regular expressions, you can also use the [class shorthand `\d`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(col, '\d', '', 'g') AS col_without_digits
FROM   tbl;
```

Comment: Ah, now I have to benchmark the two answers. Looking in to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42012/how-can-i-benchmark-a-postgresql-query. The other answer works of course so working on it. :-)

Comment: 6.076 ms versus 1.773 ms, it definitely was faster and I wonder how much more so when I get to switch my laptop to an SSD. I'll up-vote Ben and accept yours.

Comment: @John: I have been running many benchmarks over the past years. The outcome is as expected.

Comment: Not that I doubted you though I haven't benchmarked anything in PostgreSQL until today and now I've got two more updates for my MySQL/PostgreSQL cross-reference. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is `regexp_replace(string text, pattern text, replacement text [, flags text])`, using 'g' for flags makes the replacement global:

```
SELECT id, regexp_replace(_column_name_,'[0-9]','','g') AS _column_alias_
FROM _table_name_;
```

Comment: Thanks! It does work though Erwin's `translate()` was faster, up-voted at least.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove also punctuation and everything that is not an alpha:

```
SELECT id, regexp_replace(_column_name_, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g') AS _column_alias_
FROM _table_name_;
```