# Extract numbers from a field in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, conditional-statements, case, regexp-replace

I have a table with a column `po_number` of type `varchar` in Postgres 8.4. It stores alphanumeric values with some special characters. I want to ignore the characters `[/alpha/?/$/encoding/.]` and check if the column contains a number or not. If its a number then it needs to typecast as number or else pass null, as my output field `po_number_new` is a number field.

Below is the example:

[image: example]

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f79ed/2)

I tired this statement:

```
select 
(case when  regexp_replace(po_number,'[^\w],.-+\?/','') then po_number::numeric
else null
end) as po_number_new from test
```

But I got an error for explicit cast:

[image: error]

Comment: Undelete your new question, you will get an answer.  Just explain all edge cases carefully, that's all.

Comment: It's ok Tim. I will post a proper question from now-on without any edits : ) no issues. By the way thanks : )

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Simply:

```
SELECT NULLIF(regexp_replace(po_number, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric AS result
FROM   tbl;
```

`\D` being the class shorthand for "not a digit".
And you need the 4th parameter `'g'` (for "globally") to replace *all* occurrences.
[Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)

For a known, limited set of characters to replace, plain [string manipulation functions like `replace()` or `translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) are substantially cheaper. Regular expressions are just more versatile, and we want to eliminate everything *but* digits in this case. Related:

- [Regex remove all occurrences of multiple characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953099/regex-remove-all-occurrences-of-multiple-characters-in-a-string/14953266#14953266)
- [PostgreSQL SELECT only alpha characters on a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158695/postgresql-select-only-alpha-characters-on-a-row/28172693#28172693)
- [Is there a regexp_replace equivalent for postgresql 7.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094022/is-there-a-regexp-replace-equivalent-for-postgresql-7-4/34106732#34106732)

But why Postgres 8.4? [Consider upgrading to a modern version.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Consider pitfalls for outdated versions:

- [Order varchar string as numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502505/order-varchar-string-as-numeric/8502570#8502570)
- [WARNING: nonstandard use of escape in a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660471/nonstandard-use-of-escape-in-a-string-literal/39661027)

Comment: You might be interested in my proposed solution to this question - using the `TRANSLATE` function in this particularly easy case instead of the more expensive `REGEXP_REPLACE`? I'd be interested in, and grateful for, any comment(s) you may have on what I wrote! What led me here was [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306750/select-ints-from-start-of-string-separated-by-a-character-pipe-update-other-c) - a lot tricker! :-) I have a working solution for PostgreSQL and a guy I was chatting with came up with a SQL Server one - trying to do it without regexes tricky though!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

```
select (case when regexp_replace(po_number, '[^\w],.-+\?/', '') ~ '^[0-9]+$'
             then regexp_replace(po_number, '[^\w],.-+\?/', '')::numeric
        end) as po_number_new 
from test;
```

That is, you need to do the conversion on the string *after* replacement.

Note:  This assumes that the "number" is just a string of digits.

Comment: Could you explain the regexp `,.-+`? What it means?

Comment: @Abelisto I think they should be inside the brackets, though I'm not in front of Postgre right now to test it.

Comment: I am getting only nulls after using the above... instead I need numbers from each record and nulls for records that doesn't have numbers in it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract floating numbers try to use this:

```
SELECT NULLIF(regexp_replace(po_number, '[^\.\d]','','g'), '')::numeric AS result FROM tbl;
```

It's the same as Erwin Brandstetter answer but with different expression:

`[^...]` - match any character except a list of excluded characters, put the excluded charaters instead of `...`

`\.` - point character (also you can change it to `,` char)

`\d` - digit character

Answer (score 2):

The logic I would use to determine if the `po_number` field contains numeric digits is that its length should decrease when attempting to remove numeric digits.

If so, then all non numeric digits (`[^\d]`) should be removed from the `po_number` column.  Otherwise, `NULL` should be returned.

```
select case when char_length(regexp_replace(po_number, '\d', '', 'g')) < char_length(po_number)
            then regexp_replace(po_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')
            else null
       end as po_number_new
from test
```

Comment: I am getting an SQL error [42883] after trying this

Comment: @user1538020 The error was being caused by you using Postgres 8.x, which does not have a `length` function.  I updated to use `char_length` and it should work now.

Comment: I did a select version(); I am now using PostgreSQL 9.5.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit. Still getting an error. I posted the image error.

Comment: @user1538020: Asides: The error you get is due to a typo: `regex_replace` <> `regexp_replace`. And there *is* a `length()` function in pg 8.4.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : select case when char_length(regexp_replace(po_number, '\d', '', 'g')) < char_length(po_number)
            then regexp_replace(po_number, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')
            else null
       end as po_number_new
from  test;  Corrected the syntax, it now works. thanks..

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks Erwin, you're truly the king of Postgres on Stack Overflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since version 12 - that's 2 years + 4 months ago at the time of writing (but **after** the last edit that I can see on the accepted answer), you **could** use a `GENERATED FIELD` to do this quite easily on a one-time basis rather than having to calculate it each time you wish to `SELECT` a new po_number.

Furthermore, you can use the [`TRANSLATE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-translate/) function to extract your digits which is less expensive than the `REGEXP_REPLACE` [solution proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40564710/470530) by @ErwinBrandstetter!

I would do this as follows (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=01c997766f3ced770c2959ffef769ffb)):

```
CREATE TABLE s
(
  num TEXT,
  
  new_num INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (NULLIF(TRANSLATE(num, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. ', ''), '')::INTEGER) STORED
);
```

You can add to the `'ABCDEFG...` string in the `TRANSLATE` function as appropriate - I have decimal point (`.`) and a space ( ) at the end - you may wish to have more characters there depending on your input!

And checking:

```
INSERT INTO s VALUES ('2'), (''), (NULL), (' ');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2'), (''), (NULL), (' ');
SELECT * FROM s;
SELECT * FROM t;
```

Result (same for both):

```
num    new_num
  2          2
          NULL
          NULL
          NULL
```

So, I wanted to check how efficient my solution was, so I ran the following test inserting 10,000 records into both tables `s` and `t` as follows (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200391/470530)):

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)
INSERT INTO t 
with symbols(characters) as 
(
  VALUES ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
)
select string_agg(substr(characters, (random() * length(characters) + 1) :: INTEGER, 1), '')
from symbols
join generate_series(1,10) as word(chr_idx) on 1 = 1 -- word length
join generate_series(1,10000) as words(idx) on 1 = 1 -- # of words
group by idx;
```

The differences weren't that huge but the regex solution was consistently slower by about 25% - even changing the order of the tables undergoing the `INSERT`s.

However, where the `TRANSLATE` solution really shines is when doing a "raw" `SELECT` as follows:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)
SELECT
  NULLIF(TRANSLATE(num, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. ', ''), '')::INTEGER
FROM s;
```

and the same for the `REGEXP_REPLACE` solution.

The differences were very marked, the `TRANSLATE` taking approx. 25% of the time of the other function. Finally, in the interests of fairness, I also did this for both tables:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)
SELECT
  num, new_num
FROM t;
```

Both extremely quick and identical!

Comment: Yes, regular expression functions are known to be substantially more expensive (got faster in recent versions, but still). I've kept pointing that out over the last decade: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28172693/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34106732/939860, ... However, listing all possible non-digits was somewhat more practical in times of ASCII, not so much with UTF ...